# Node-Red OPC-UA Server only working for Double?

Tags: node-red, opc-ua

I am trying to create an OPC-UA server in Node-Red using `node-red-contrib-opcua-server` version 1.1.1. This works quite well for values declared as `double`.

The flow for this looks quite simple [image]

The configuration of the Node Compact server for a `double` value looks like this (and thus pretty much follows the example)

```
const WC01_raw_mat = namespace.addVariable({
 "organizedBy": wc01,
 "browseName": "raw_mat",
 "nodeId": "ns=1;s=wc01_raw_mat",
 "dataType": "Double",
 "value": {
   "get": function () {
     return new Variant({
       "dataType": DataType.Double,
       "value": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get("WC01_raw_mat")
     });
   },
   "set": function (variant) {
     flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(
       "WC01_raw_mat",
       parseFloat(variant.value)
     );
     return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;
   }
 }});
```

If I check the value with an OPC-UA Client I can see my `double` with a value `0.0`

[image]

However, my attempt to transfer an `integer` or `string` in addition to a `double` value fails. The adjustments for `integers` look like this:

```
const WC01_raw_mat = namespace.addVariable({
 "organizedBy": wc01,
 "browseName": "raw_mat",
 "nodeId": "ns=1;s=wc01_raw_mat",
 "dataType": "Integer",
 "value": {
   "get": function () {
     return new Variant({
       "dataType": DataType.Integer,
       "value": flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.get("WC01_raw_mat")
     });
   },
   "set": function (variant) {
     flexServerInternals.sandboxFlowContext.set(
       "WC01_raw_mat",
       parseInt(variant.value)
     );
     return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;
   }
 }});
```

(Modifications I made: `"dataType": "Integer"`,`"dataType": DataType.Integer`,`parseInt(variant.value)` )
Unfortunately, no more data is displayed.

[image]

So, what did I made wrong or what did I miss? I am grateful for any tips.

Comment: After some trial and error, I have now found the right solution. I'll describe it here so that it might help someone in the future.

For the representation of integer values I finally used ```UInt32``` and for both ```dataType``` 
A text can be displayed as ```LocalisedText```